# How to remove css class from a particular tag?

Tags: html, css

I have a css class for all anchor tags like below:

```
a, a font{color:#184c75 !important;}
```

Now I want to remove this color css for one of my anchor tags which is below

```
 <a class="button button-border button-light button-rounded uppercase nomargin readMore">See More</a>
```

But when I just remove my class it's effecting to all of my anchor tags, but I just want to apply color white to this particular anchor tag only. Can anyone please help?

Comment: put an `id` for that class :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a more specific selector like `a.classname` or chained `a.classname1.classname2` etc to override the previous rules.

I used `gray` color rather than `white` in the example below for the demo purpose.

```css
a, a font{color:#184c75 !important;}
a.button-light, a.button-light font{color:gray !important;}
```

```html
<a class="button button-border button-light button-rounded uppercase nomargin readMore">See More</a>
```

Side note, avoid using `!important` is highly recommended in general.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `:not()` in your selector to exclude things from that rule. Here I'm using the `.readMore` class to target the link in your example, but you would use whatever makes sense on your site.

```css
a:not(.readMore), a font{color:#184c75 !important;}
```

```html
 <a class="button button-border button-light button-rounded uppercase nomargin readMore">See More</a>
```